# Xamarin.Forms.Mac - Loading Overlay Bug

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've made a little Library a while ago for Xamarin.Forms and inside there is custom ContentPage. This class has a Loading Overlay methods inside:

```
    public async Task ShowLoadingOverlayAsync(string loadingMessage)
    {
        // If there is already an Overlay
        if (LoadingOverlay != null)
        {
            // Update the Text
            await UpdateLoadingOverlayAsync(loadingMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Store the actual content
        var CashedContentView = TheView.Content;

        // Create a Grid to show the actual view and the overlay
        var grid = new Grid();

        // Add the actual view
        grid.Children.Add(CashedContentView);

        // Create the Overlay
        LoadingOverlay = new StandardLoadingOverlay();
        LoadingOverlay.Content.Opacity = opacity;
        LoadingOverlay.LoadingText = loadingMessage;

        // Add the Overlay to the grid
        grid.Children.Add(LoadingOverlay.Content);

        // Set the Grid as the Content
        TheView.Content = grid;
    }
```

This method is simply displaying a LoadingOverlay on top of the actual View. For more Details, look at the code, I commented the most important actions for you to understand a little better.

My Page.xaml does look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mvvm:BaseContentPage 
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
x:Class="Lama.Forms.Source.UI.Pages.LoginPages.LoginPage"
xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:SharpLibrary.Forms.Source.MVVM;assembly=SharpLibrary.Forms"
xmlns:ccEntries="clr-namespace:SharpLibrary.Forms.Source.CustomControls.Entries;assembly=SharpLibrary.Forms"
xmlns:ccLabels="clr-namespace:Gorilla.Forms.Source.UI.CustomControls.Labels"
BackgroundColor="Black"
>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <RelativeLayout
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        >

        <!-- <Image Style="{StaticResource StandardBackgroundImage}" /> -->
        <ScrollView
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint = "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint = "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}" 
            >
            <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" HasShadow="false" Padding="0">

            <StackLayout  
                Margin="0, 200, 0, 0"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="400">

                <ccEntries:IconedRoundedEntry x:Name="txtEmail"
                    Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Icon="{Binding EmailIcon}"
                    TextColor="White"
                    Placeholder="Email"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LamaStandardColor1}"
                    />

                <ccEntries:IconedRoundedEntry x:Name="txtPassword"
                    Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Icon="{Binding PasswordIcon}"
                    TextColor="White"
                    Placeholder="Password"
                    IsPassword="True"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LamaStandardColor1}"
                    />

                <Button Style="{StaticResource RedButton}" x:Name="btnLogin"
                    Text="LOGIN" 
                    Margin="0,30,0,0" 
                    Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" />

                <Label Text="No Account yet? Register now" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CreateAccountCommand}"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>

                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</mvvm:BaseContentPage>
```

So in Detail, the Method stores the actual Content, creates a Grid, adds the stored Content and finally displays the LoadingOverlay on top.
This works really good as a Xamarin.Forms.iOS app, but when I run the exact same code as a Xamarin.Forms.Mac project, the stored Content disappears when the Loading Overlay is displayed.

For sure there is a HideLoadingOverlay Method where the LoadingOverlay disappears and the stored Content comes back as the Main Content again.. This works as intended on iOS AND on MacOS.

So my guess is, that there is a unimplemented Method / Property in the Xamarin.Forms.MacOS Framework which prevents my plan.

Maybe someone sees or knows something I don't.
So thanks for your helping hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally fugured out a much better way to implement a Loading Overlay.

**First of all: The far planes of the WWW recommend doing the above "Hack" to implement such an Overlay, but my Solution is way more efficient, performant and easier to understand. Also I found out that using the "bad" way and having a larger image inside your view, e.g. a iamge as the Header, it tries everytime the Overlay appears to reload the image. This results in a completly laggy UI and annoying loading times. With my solution this case completly diappered.**

My way needs the Actual View to contain a Container. Because I want all my Views to be able to show an Overlay, I made a Templated ContentPage and BaseViewModel but for simplicity I'll show it with no base classes.

**Note:** I wrapped the Views inside a RelativeLayout, so it is easy to make the View fill the whole screen.

First of all, add the Container to your View

```
<!-- This is the Content of your View -->
<Grid .../>

<!-- The empty Content for the Loading Overlay -->
<ContentView x:Name="CvOverlayContainer" BackgroundColor="Transparent" IsVisible="false"
    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}"/>
```

**Note:** The OverlayContainer must be invisible because else it prevens Gestures to be recognized

Next the ViewModel needs a Object it can use to show / hide the LoadingOverlay:

```
public ContentView LoadingOverlayContainer { get; set; }
```

This  ContentView will be initialized when setting the ViewModel inside the Code-Behind file of our View:

```
// Set the ViewModel
ViewModel = new MainPageViewModel(this)
{
    LoadingOverlayContainer =  CvOverlayContainer
};
```

And finally we can now show the Overlay:

```
public async Task ShowLoadingOverlayAsync(string loadingMessage)
    {
        // If there is already an Overlay
        if (LoadingOverlay != null)
        {
            // Update the Text
            await UpdateLoadingOverlayAsync(loadingMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Create the Overlay
        LoadingOverlay = new StandardLoadingOverlay();

        LoadingOverlayContainer.IsVisible = true;
        LoadingOverlayContainer.Content = LoadingOverlay.Content;
    }

    public async Task UpdateLoadingOverlayAsync(string loadingMessage)
    {
        if (LoadingOverlay != null)
        {
            LoadingOverlay.LoadingText = loadingMessage;
        }
    }

    public async Task HideLoadingOverlayAsync()
    {
        if (LoadingOverlay == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Fade out the Overlay
        await LoadingOverlay.Content.FadeTo(0, 300);

        // Release the Memory
        LoadingOverlay = null;

        // Set the Container as invisible again, so that the UI is recognizable for gestures
        LoadingOverlayContainer.IsVisible = false;

    }
```

Maybe this Solution helps someone to implement their own Overlays